# Weird spacing in the document

Tags: spacing

I've been spending hours trying to understand why there is some weird spacing in my (very long) Latex document, but I haven't been able to figure it out...
basically the weird spacing appears after Theorems or Propositions, and it appears **only if** I use this package:

```
% Set interline
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
```

The extra space appears randomly, not after every Theorem or Proposition, but only after some of them. In the screenshot you can see what I mean:

[image]

Equation (3.3.20) ends a `theorem` environment, and the following line is immediately subsequent in the code, without skips or `\\`, so I really don't get why that wide blank space is there.

In the document, I have never used the `[H]` positioner, neither in tables nor in figures.

If I comment the `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\setstretch{1.2}` lines, then everything looks fine; however, I'd like to use those commands (or equivalent commands) to have some spacing between the lines.

Can please anyone help?

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem? Without knowledge of your class, packages and other settings is quite difficult to debug this.

Comment: write `\raggedbottom` into your preamble

Comment: you have not provided any usable code to let anyone debug but presumably you have `\flushbottom` (or a book class that defaults to that) and whatever is at the top of the following page is something large and unbreakable.

Comment: Please give more information, latex _never_ adds space randomly, it just follows the instructions in your document, but if you do not show any of your code it is hard to guess what is specifying that space.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}`, adding `\raggedbottom` solves the problem

Comment: `\raggedbottom` will move the space to the bottom of the page, but the underlying problem, that that page does not have enough content, is still there. Presumably there is something on the next page that is causing that.